# JCenter Maven repository is no longer receiving updates: newer library versions may be available elsewhere

Tags: android, android-studio, maven, warnings, jcenter

I am getting this warning in project level build.gradle file in android studio.

```
Warning:(22, 9) JCenter Maven repository is no longer receiving updates: newer library versions may be available elsewhere
```

What is supposed to be done. I tried removing it and got a long list of errors as below.

```
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.7.10/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-settings-api:7.4.2
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.4.2
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > com.android.tools:repository:30.4.2
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > com.android.tools.build:aaptcompiler:7.4.2
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:30.4.2
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-model:30.4.2
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:7.4.2
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-host-retention-proto:30.4.2
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.4.2
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > com.android.tools.build:builder-model:7.4.2
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:7.4.2
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.4.2 > com.android.tools:common:30.4.2
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.4.2 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:30.4.2
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.4.2 > com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:30.4.2
   > Could not find org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.6.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.5.6/httpmime-4.5.6.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.....
```

And the possible solution is given as follows:

```
Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

What shall I do to remove the warning?

This is my project level build.gradle, where I am getting the warning:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: The slot only shows access to Google repo, are you sure you have not forgot to add Maven Central repo? Also based on your question it is not clear where the JCenter message fits in (the artifact the question is all about is not mentioned). Have you forgotten to post relevant information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved: To remove this warning replace:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

with

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```